# How to access and render a component in an array dynamically, based on a selected index?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects that have a key `Component`, which points to its respective component.

I'm able to map over the array and display all components like this,

```
dict.map(({ Component }) => <Component />
```

And that works, however I'm trying to conditionally render specific components. In my case, I'm trying to access the `Component` property at index `1`, however it doesn't seem to work. The way I'm trying to access it is something like, `dict[displayComponentAtIndex].Component`, where `displayComponentAtIndex` is part of the state.

How can I render the component the way I want to?

[image: blissful-meitner-bzbt7]

Comment: This is because you are getting the Component as the object not react component. If you do this `{displayComponentAtIndex === 1 && <Component1></Component1>}` it would work

Comment: Could you try doing like below
```const TargetComponent = dict[displayComponentAtIndex].Component; 
return <TargetComponent />;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your `dict.js` to

```
export default [{ Component: (<Component1></Component1>) }, { Component: <Component2></Component2> }];
```

As you need component and not object to render.